# Is there any reason why TrafficStats values might be reset apart from on Shutdown?

Tags: android

My app uses `TrafficStats` to measure the incoming bytes from the 3G connection. For some reason, when running my app on my friend's Samsung Galaxy SII, it appears that the value is reset to zero after a certain period of time.

I realise that when the device is rebooted the value is returned to zero, and I have accounted for that, but for some reason on his device it just does it occasionally, possibly once per day.

Using my own device (HTC Desire) I do not have this problem. I read that apps are not able to reset the value so it shouldn't be another app causing the problem.

Is there any reason why this might happen? Are there any known device specific quirks for the Galaxy SII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the cuff, this may be a Samsung thing, as [the same problem was reported for the Galaxy Tab 10.1](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19938).

All that I can recommend is that, at least for these devices, you increase your sampling frequency, so the time difference between your last reading and the high value when the reset occurs is lower, so your overall data is more accurate. Or, throw out the reading that occurs with the reset.