# Measure intermediate throughput when writing to OutputStream [or] Why is write() blocking, while read() is not?

Tags: java, android, nio, apache-commons, java-io

I need to measure the intermediate throughput of uploading and downloading a large file (via FTP using [Apache Commons Net API](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)).

**Download:** (No problems)

Everything is fine for downloading, which uses code like the following:

```
InputStream is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(filePath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[256 * 1024];
int read;

while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Read = " + read);
}
```

Here, the buffer is 256 KB in size, and the total size of the file being downloaded is 1 MB. Still each individual call to `is.read()` returns only about 2 KB. In this case `read()` **does not block** until the buffer is full. This enables me to measure intermediate download throughput. So far so good.

**Upload:** (Problematic)

Now comes the pain. When I allocate a similar sized buffer to write to an `OutputStream`, the call to `write()` blocks until the entire 256 KB is written.

Why does only `write()` block, whereas `read()` doesn't?

So I tried to use [`nio`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html). Unlike `Outputstream`'s write(), the write() method of `WritableByteChannel` returns the number of bytes actually written. So it must be non-blocking, right? No such luck. This `write()` also blocks until the whole buffer is written. Here is the code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[256 * 1024];
new Random.nextBytes(byteArray);

OutputStream os = ftp.storeFileStream(filePath);
WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(os);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
int written = channel.write(byteBuffer);
```

So how can I measure the intermediate throughput when the upload is blocking?

One way is to use Android's [`TrafficStats` API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html). But it comes with its own set of frustrations. As per the documentation, these statistics may not be available on all platforms. Also it needs handling of scenarios like integer counter overflow (after 2GB), and [counter reset bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9083579/165674) [on some platforms](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19938) when switching between 3G and Wifi.

Can someone show me a way out?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does only write() block, whereas read() doesn't?

Because that's the way the underlying operating system behaves.